# Custom post type with custom fields enabled, is there a way to set a default group of fileds?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I defined the custom postype: property, like this

```
function register_cpt_property() {

        $labels = array( 
            'name' => _x( 'properties', 'property' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'property', 'property' ),
            'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'property' ),
            'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New property', 'property' ),
            'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit property', 'property' ),
            'new_item' => _x( 'New property', 'property' ),
            'view_item' => _x( 'View property', 'property' ),
            'search_items' => _x( 'Search properties', 'property' ),
            'not_found' => _x( 'No properties found', 'property' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No properties found in Trash', 'property' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent property:', 'property' ),
            'menu_name' => _x( 'properties', 'property' ),
        );

        $args = array( 
            'labels' => $labels,
            'hierarchical' => false,

            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'zone', 'rent' ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,


            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'can_export' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post'
        );

        register_post_type( 'property', $args );
    }
```

The thing is that this generates this module:

[image]

Wich asks the user for wich custom fields to use, wich is great; but, is there a way to set a default group? Something that makes this module, initially, like this?

[image]

( I want to Do this so the user doesn't forget any of these.. But it's ok if he wants to add more)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: [add a meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) with your preset fields. lots of examples on this site or via google to get you started.

Comment: So you mean using metaboxes instead of enabling custom fields? thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta Boxes are what you need.

```
function add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context, $priority, $callback_args );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box' );
```

Set the custom post type in the 4th parameter. This should get you started:

[Custom Meta Box in WordPress Post Pages and Custom Post Type](http://www.itsabhik.com/wordpress-custom-meta-box/)

Comment: Thanks for your anwer! So what would it look for (just one field) the example I posted?

Comment: Try this.. `add_meta_box( 'mymetaboxid', 'Meta Box Title', 'function_to_output_html', array('property'), 'advanced', 'high' );`. The source I posted explains that well.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not really what I wanted to do... i would like just to set a default group of inputs for the custom fields.. thanks anyways!

Comment: Do you mean default values for the fields? Either way, you'll need the meta boxes.

Comment: No, no default values; default fields to be asked..